# Could $ can be used as a concatenated symbol in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash

I have read a `BASH` script, and found the following line:

```
lines="$lines"$'\n'
```

After testing, I know the meaning of this line is adding a "`\n`" after the string "`$lines`".

But after checking the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.txt), I can't find "`$`" can be used as a concatenated symbol. Could anyone give explainations on this usage of "`$`"? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Read the paragrah "Quoting" in the manual pages. [Read this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly closer read of the `Bash Manual` under `Quoting` would reveal where this gem is hidden. Specifically:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
>   string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
>   ANSI C standard.

Used specifically in the context of `\n` it provdes a `new line`. You most often see this form of quoting used in regard to the Bash `IFS` (internal field separator) whose default is `space` `tab` `newline` written:

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

Comment: `lines="abcd"$'\nef'`; `echo $lines` => `abcd ef`. Why `\n` is outputted as a space? Thanks!

Comment: The `\n` is decimal `10` or hex `0xa`. These are characters in the `non-printable` range of characters on the ASCII chart. So you get a `blank` (or some other weird symbol when printing directly). The easy quick `strcat` (is strcat itself) or say `newstr = strdup (strcat (strcat (str1, " "), str2))` and other variations that take advantage of `strdup`'s ability to dynamically allocate memory sufficient to handle the string. (you are responsible for freeing that memory later :)

Comment: `lines="abcd"$'\nef'`;`echo $lines` => `abcd ef`, I think `\n` should be outputted as a new line, so the whole output should be `"abcd(new line)ef"`

Comment: Why not `lines="abcd"; suffix="ef"; new="${lines}${suffix}" => abcdef`

Comment: i just do a test, and find the result can't be explained. So I want to drill down it, thanks!

Comment: But you do understand that `lines="abcd"$'\nef' => abcd ef` is caused by `\n = 0xa` which is `non-printable ASCII`, right? Also, since this is Bash, concatenation is fairly simple. If you are using `echo` to test the result, make sure you use `echo -e` or `printf` otherwise, you do **NOT** get the extended ASCII set. Using `printf with "abcd"$'\nef' will produce a `newline`

Comment: Oh, I see. `$'\n'` can be extended, but `BASH` can't expand the `'\n'` in `$'\nef'`to new line. Right? BTW, very sorry for interrupting you so much!

Comment: It's not that `\n` is unprintable; when `$lines` is unquoted, the newline is simply treated as whitespace that is used for word-splitting, resulting in `echo` receiving two separate arguments "abcd" and "ef", which is prints separated by a single space. Quoting (`echo "$line"`) will preserve the newline as a literal character, producing two lines of output.

Comment: `printf "abcd\nef"` would produce a new line as well, since `printf` itself treats `\n` as a newline character without needing the `$'...'`-style quoting.